# Persist grid filters

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to persist the filters of a Kendo-Grid so that when the page is left and returned to, the filters can be re-applied.

I have found jQuery examples online but I can't find any for Vue.js. The jQuery ones deal with dynamically added grids rather than one specified as HTML format.

I know that this is possible as I have done it before but unfortunately I can't remember how, and that code is no longer available.

For example:

```
    <kendo-grid :dataBound="dataBound" :selectable="'multiple row'" height="580" id="dataGrid" ref="grid" :resizable="true" :data-source="dataContent" :filterable="true" :sortable="true" :change="onChange" @filterChange="saveFilter()">
        <kendo-grid-column :field="'Code'" :title="'Code'" :width="150" :attributes="{ 'class': 'text-nowrap'}"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column :field="'Name'" :title="'Name'" :width="200" :attributes="{ 'class': 'text-nowrap'}"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column :field="'Balance'" :title="'Balance'" :width="150" format="{0:c}" :aggregates="['sum']" :footer-template="balanceFooterTemplate" :attributes="{ 'class': 'currency-right red-if-minus' }" :header-attributes="{ 'class': 'header-right-align'}"></kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```

What code do I need to read the filter (if any) and re-apply it?

Test saveFilter event:

```
saveFilter: function () {
    console.log('saveFilter called');
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Vue.js, but is this the sample you refer to? https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-persist-customized-filter   As long as you can get a reference to your grid, can't you modify this to work with your code?

Comment: @G_P Yes that's the one. You can see the properties and events etc they use to manage the filter, but when I try to use it in vue, e.g. with `@filterchange="saveFilter()"` nothing actually happens.

Comment: is saveFilter your code? If so can you post that? When you say nothing happens, does the function not get called at all?

Answer (score 0):

I just found [a Vue example of saving/loading grid state](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid-wrapper/persist-state/).

It uses buttons to save and load state of the grid, however, I would think you could save your state on each filter change.

Code:

```
<template>
<kendo-datasource ref="datasource1"
                      :type="'odata'"
                      :transport-read-url="'https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers'"
                      :page-size='20'>
    </kendo-datasource>

    <a href="#" class="k-button" v-on:click="saveState">Save State</a>
    <a href="#" class="k-button" v-on:click="loadState">Load State</a>

    <kendo-grid ref="grid"
                :height="600"
                :data-source-ref="'datasource1'"
                :groupable="true"
                :sortable="true"
                :reorderable="true"
                :resizable="true"
                :column-menu="true"
                :filterable-mode="'row'"
                :pageable-refresh="true"
                :pageable-page-sizes="true"
                :pageable-button-count="5">
        <kendo-grid-column :field="'ContactName'"
                           :title="'Contact Name'"
                           :width="250"
                           :locked="true"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column :field="'ContactTitle'"
                           :title="'Contact Title'"
                           :width="350"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column :field="'CompanyName'"
                           :title="'Company Name'"
                           :width="350"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column :field="'Country'"
                           :width="450"></kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
</template>
<script>
import { Grid, GridColumn } from '@progress/kendo-grid-vue-wrapper';
import { KendoDataSource } from '@progress/kendo-datasource-vue-wrapper';

export default {
    components: {
        'kendo-grid': Grid,
        'kendo-grid-column': GridColumn,
        'kendo-datasource': KendoDataSource
    },
    data () {
        return {
            schemaModelFields: {
                UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                ProductName: { type: "string" },
                UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                UnitsOnOrder: { type: "number" },
                UnitsInStock: { type: "number" }
            },
            groupDefinition: {
                field: "UnitsInStock",
                aggregates: [
                    { field: "ProductName", aggregate: "count" },
                    { field: "UnitPrice", aggregate: "sum"},
                    { field: "UnitsOnOrder", aggregate: "average" },
                    { field: "UnitsInStock", aggregate: "count" }
                ]
            },
            aggregateDefinition: [
                { field: "ProductName", aggregate: "count" },
                { field: "UnitPrice", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "UnitsOnOrder", aggregate: "average" },
                { field: "UnitsInStock", aggregate: "min" },
                { field: "UnitsInStock", aggregate: "max" }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        saveState: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var grid = this.$refs.grid.kendoWidget();

            localStorage["kendo-grid-options"] = kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions());
        },
        loadState: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var options = localStorage["kendo-grid-options"];
            var grid = this.$refs.grid.kendoWidget();

            if (options) {
                grid.setOptions(JSON.parse(options));
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Good find! That looks like half of it, now I need to trigger it when the filter is changed somehow. There is a `filterChange` event but it doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G I don't know enough about Vue to see what the difference is between that example and the one here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/filtering/  which shows the filterchange event, and the event fires in the StackBlitz example on that page